# Online-Schreibstilkorrektur?

Tags: style, resource, online-resource

Gibt es sowas wie eine [Online-Rechtschreibprüfung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibpruefung-online) für Schreibstil und Lesbarkeit? Angeblich hat [Papyrus](http://www.papyrus.de/besonderheiten/stilanalyse/) sowas, aber das ist nicht online zugänglich und kostet viel Geld. Ich suche das für eine einmalige Sache (Bachelorarbeit).

Ganz toll wäre, wenn das als Input Latex oder PDF versteht...

Comment: Ganz ehrlich? Gib deine Bachelorarbeit einem Kommilitonen oder einem Kollegen der Firma, für die du die Arbeit schreibst, zum Korrekturlesen. Am besten einem, dessen Stil hinreichend sauber ist. Hier würde ich keiner automatisierten Prüfung oder Korrektur trauen, erst recht nicht im Deutschen.

Comment: War auch eher so als Vorstufe gedacht bevor ich das jemandem zumute. Aus Höflichkeit. Außerdem wäre so ein Tool auch sonst gaz nett.

Comment: Also doch nicht als einmalige Sache?

Comment: Es wäre generell nützlich, aber nur eine Sache ist akut. Wenn ich nochmal eine Bachelorarbeit schreibe erfinde ich sowas und schreibe darüber....

Comment: Sagen wir's so: Es hat vermutlich schon seinen Grund, wenn die Herren von Papyrus so viel Geld dafür haben wollen - wenn irgendein kostenloser oder günstiger Onlinedienst dasselbe könnte, hätten sie kein Geschäftsmodell :)

Comment: @OregonGhost: Vordergründig einleuchtend. Tatsächlich habe ich schon Programme gesehen, die deutlich mehr kosten als bessere, die nichts kosten. Ein Geschäftsmodell hat man, solange die Kunden mehr zahlen als es kostet, ganz unabhängig davon ob es Gratiskonkurrenz gibt, und ob die besser oder schlechter ist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt tatsächlich einige Tools, die durchaus nützlich sein und die Analyse Deines Stils unterstützen können - einen menschlichen Gegenleser kann keines auch nur ansatzweise ersetzen. Folgende Tools *ergänzen* einander:

- Durchaus brauchbar (im statistischen Sinne) ist [LeichtLesbar](http://www.leichtlesbar.ch/html/) - es zählt die Wörter und Silben und errechnet einen sog. *Fleischwert*, der etwas über die Qualität des Texts aussagen soll.
- Mein Lieblingstool, das einen bestimmten Aspekt beleuchtet, ist das [Blabla-Meter](http://www.blablameter.de/). Werbebroschüren und Politikerreden werden hier schnell entlarvt.
- Interessant ist auch eine Hervorhebung aller Füllwörter des Texts [hier](http://www.lemontree.de/schreibschule/). Rechts oben ist ein Link auf den sog. [Füllwortterminator](http://www.lemontree.de/schreibschule/FuellWort/Counter.htm).
- Ähnlich wie LeichtLesbar arbeitet [diese Seite](http://www.it-agile.de/stil/index.html) - man erhält eine Auswertung des Texts und ebenfalls einen Fleischwert.
- Etwas scherzhafter (aber wer weiß) geht es im [Stiltest der FAZ](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buecher/ich-schreibe-wie/stiltest-ich-schreibe-wie-11480570.html) zu.

Es macht wirklich Spaß, hin und wieder eigenen Texte analysieren zu lassen. Insbesondere der Hinweis auf sinnlose Füllwörter kann einem wirklich helfen, Informationsdichte und Textfluss zu verbessern.

PDFs liest keines der Tools, den Text einzukopieren sollte aber kein Problem sein.

Lt. Stiltest ist diese Antwort übrigens im Stile von Franz Kafka verfasst, auf eine von Theodor Fontane gestellte Frage.

Answer (score 1):

Eine vernünftige und sicher funktionierende Rechtschreibprüfung für Schreibstil und Lesbarkeit gibt es zurzeit noch nicht. Das gilt auch für die normale Prüfung der Rechtschreibung.

Das liegt daran, dass dafür eine künstliche Intelligenz (KI) benötigt wird, die herkömmliche (Home-)Rechner noch nicht leisten können. Grundlage dafür ist der Bereich der theoretischen Sprachen in der Informatik (für Nicht-Informatiker: ein Compiler für beispielsweise C oder C++ basiert darauf) und die KI (z. B. neuronale Netze, die heute bereits Gesichter erkennen können oder anhand der Art und Weise wie die Tastatur verwendet wird, erkennen können, wer den Computer bedient). Um einen Satz korrekt beurteilen zu können, muss die Software die einzelnen Satzelemente wie Subjekt, Prädikat, Objekt usw. eineindeutig (da steckt das eigentliche Problem!) identifizieren und entsprechend bewerten. Das ist extrem rechenintensiv und nicht trivial.

Papyrus setzt das von Duden erwerbbare Werkzeug "Duden-Korrektor" ein (siehe in der Frage angegebener Link), der auch in andere Textverarbeitungsprogramme wie Word integrierbar ist (nicht kostenfrei, liefert aber relativ gute Ergebnisse).

Die beste automatische Silbentrennung, die ich kenne, ist in LaTeX (genauer pdfLaTeX, mit Paket "babel" für deutsche Sprache) integriert.

Eine übliche Rechtschreibprüfung (wie sie z. B. in Word eingebaut ist) hilft lediglich, Buchstabendreher wie "wei" statt "wie" oder "dei" statt "die" zu vermeiden, eine verlässliche Rechtschreibprüfung ist sie nicht (und kann sie zurzeit auch nicht sein; basiert darauf, ob das Wort bekannt ist, semantische Zusammenhänge werden nicht geprüft (dafür wäre eine eingebaute KI notwendig, z. B. bei "beleibte Fehler" statt richtig "beliebte Fehler"). So wird bspw. "die die" als Fehler ausgewiesen, obwohl es richtig sein kann.).

**Fazit:**

Eine Abschlussarbeit sollte immer von **mindestens drei** anderen Personen zur Kontrolle gelesen werden. Idealerweise ist mindestens ein Mensch dabei, der nicht aus dem Fach ist und der so besser die Verständlichkeit des Textes beurteilen kann.

**Tipp 1:**

Das Korrekturlesen einer Arbeit sollte immer mit Hilfe eines Papierausdruckes erfolgen, da wir Menschen Text auf dem Bildschirm anders lesen als Text auf dem Papier. Beim Korrekturlesen mit Papier werden grundsätzlich mehr enthaltene Fehler gefunden.

**Tipp 2:**

Als Autor einer Abschlussarbeit liest man sehr schnell nicht mehr das, was auf dem Papier/Schirm steht, sondern das, was da stehen *soll*.

**Abhilfe:** Text eine Woche liegen lassen oder Sätze rückwärts lesen (dann muss man wirklich lesen, was da steht …).

**Schlussbemerkung:**

Eine große Anzahl meiner Studenten durfte die Richtigkeit obiger Beobachtungen bereits persönlich erfahren und teilweise auch durchleiden …

Comment: Schöne Antwort, zufällig studiere ich Informatik. Ich hätte allerdings angenommen, dass formale Sprachen nicht viel mit deutscher Grammatik zu tun haben, die selten eindeutig ist. Viel mehr denke ich liegt das dürftige Abschneiden derzeitiger Systeme in fehlendem Hintergrundwissen was ein menschlicher Leser unweigerlich nutzt. Nach der Selbstdarstellung von Papyrus ist deren Stilprüfung "einzigartig" und beschränkt sich nicht auf die Duden-Werkzeuge. Das mit dem Korrekturlesen mache ich sowieso, ich habe das als Vorstufe gedacht um offensichtliche Sachen zu finden die man selbst nicht sieht.